# Query subdocuments in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

As a simplified example, I have "book" documents stored in elastic search so that a request `GET /myindex/book/1` returns something like

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Hamlet",
  "author": "William Shakespeare",
  "pages": [
    {"page_id": 1, "contents": "hello, world . . . this story is very well written"},
    {"page_id": 5, "contents": "goodbye, world . . . i am done writing this book"}
  ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is run some sort of query that will get me records with individual matching pages. That is something like `GET /myindex/book/_mySpecialQuery?q=hello` would have results `[{"page_id": 1, "contents": "hello, world . . . this story is very well written", "_parent": 1}]` and  `GET /myindex/book/_mySpecialQuery?q=world` would have results `[{"page_id": 1, "contents": "hello, world . . . this story is very well written", "_parent": 1}, {"page_id": 5, "contents": "goodbye, world . . . i am done writing this book", "_parent": 1}]` where `_parent` is the book's ID.

I cannot easily denormalize the data since it is coming from Mongo (via mongo-connector).

---

(This seems like it should be simple but I haven't seen any good ways to do this -- please do comment with a link if I'm just looking at the wrong terminology etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) with [requesting fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html); it should do the job:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
              "pages.contents": "hello"
         }
    },
    "fields": [
        "pages.page_id",
        "pages.contents",
        "id"
    ]
}
```

Your result will be returned in the `hits` and is going to look like this:

```
[
    {
    "_index": <YOUR_INDEX_NAME>,
    "_type": <YOUR_TYPE_NAME>,
    "_id": 1,
    "_score": <SOME SCORE VALUE>,
    "fields": {
        "pages.page_id": [
            1
        ],
        "pages.contents": [
            "hello, world . . . this story is very well written"
        ],
        "id": [
              1
        ]
    }
    }
]
```

NOTE: I'm afraid the book's id is going to be still called `id` (in the fields, as part of the source), and `_id` (as id of the document), but not `_parent` (like you wished)